# How could I structure this database?

Tags: sql, database-design

We have a database that has a bunch of categories in each. The hierarchy is like this:

```
Department
-- Necklaces
   -- N_Diamond
      -- N_D_Silver
   -- N_Silver
-- Rings
   -- R_Diamond
   -- R_Gemstone
```

Each of the top level categories (Necklaces, Rings) has one parent category (Department) and each category within those top level categories will only have one parent category (i.e. N_Diamond is the parent of N_D_Silver).

In each of these categories, there will be a list of products. Each product can belong to multiple categories (one-to-many?).

How can I go about organizing this in a database? A table for products where each row is a product + a category it is in? This means each product can have several rows. This doesn't seem very normalized, though.

Comment: I wonder if the child categories (Necklaces, Rings, N_Diamond etc) have attributes/fields by itself because this could be a case of `generalization/specialization` or `superclass/subclass` otherwise you have just to create reference tables as the answers already given below indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Use a tree structure
table will have `rows id`, `parent_category`, `child_category`.
So a typical row would be

```
1, Departments, Necklace
2, Departments, Rings
3, Neckless, N_Diamonds
3, Neckless, N_Silver
...
10, R_Gemstone, null
```

You can normalize this by indexing.

Now create a table for products which reference the tree above
`Product_Table` `rows id`, `category_id`, `product_name`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, this sentence: "You can normalize this by indexing."  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry for the lateness, I meant to say instead of repeating the text N Diamonds or Necklace, you can make another table called ProductType with attributes id, type, description and then just reference using the foreign key of the product type id

Answer (score 0):

Could be simply:

```
Product (ProductID, Name, details)
Department (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, ParentDepartmentID)
ProductDepartment (DepartmentID, ProductID)
```

You could separate the hierarchy of department levels into different tables, ideal depends on use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd model it something along these lines:

```
create table dbo.Type
(
  id int not null identity(1,1) primary key ,
)

create table dbo.TypeAttribute
(
  typeId int not null foreign key references dbo.Type(id) ,
  id     int not null identity(1,1) unique ,

  primary key ( typeId , id ) ,

)

create table dbo.Product
(
  id     int not null identity(1,1) unique ,
  typeId int not null foreign key references dbo.Type(id) ,

  primary key ( id , typeId ) ,
)

create table dbo.ProductAttribute
(
  productId   int not null ,
  typeId      int not null ,
  attributeId int not null ,

  primary key ( productId , typeId , attributeId ) ,
  foreign key ( productId , typeId      ) references dbo.Product       ( id     , typeId ) ,
  foreign key ( typeId    , attributeId ) references dbo.TypeAttribute ( typeId , id    ) ,

)
```

- we have a distinct set of `Types`, the parent category of product.
- each such `Type` has some number of `TypeAttributes`, descriptive attributes for items of that particular type.
- We have a number of `Products`, each of which is assigned to one and only one `Type`.
- We have an associative entity, `ProductAttribute`, enumerating the attributes possessed by each unique product, drawn from the available attributes for that product's `Type`.